# Move Zipped Folder from PHP Server to Client

Tags: php, wordpress, download, zip

I am using Wordpress. I have created a form in which users check which files to be included in a zipped folder and the folder containing the files is created on the server.

**My question is how do I move this newly created zipped folder to the client?** I would like the user to be able to select where on the client the folder is downloaded as well.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="<?php echo $path; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="download" value="Download Selected">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset( $_POST['download'] ) && !empty($_POST['checked']) ){
$files = $_POST['checked'];
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = time().".zip"; // Zip name
$zip->open($zip_name,  ZipArchive::CREATE);
$full = wp_upload_dir();
$base = $full['baseurl'] .'/';

if (is_array($files)){
        foreach ($_POST['checked'] as $file) {

          echo $full_path = $file;
          echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $full_path;
          if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bcg/wp-content/uploads/'.$full_path)){
              $zip->addFromString(basename($base . $full_path),  file_get_contents($base . $full_path)); 
              echo 'file exists'; 
              bcg_download_function($zip_name);
          }
          else{
           echo"file does not exist";
          }
        }

        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zip_name);
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zip_name));
        readfile($zip_name);
        $zip->close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ajax technology.

1. Rename your `input type="submit"` to `input type="button"`
2. Intercept click on this button in your js code
3. On click, post ajax request from browser to your server
4. In ajax processing function, use php code shown here, **form and return a link** to newly created zip
5. In your js code, in ajax success function, get this link and show it to the user.

You can read detailed manual how to use ajax in WordPress [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Working on this now. I've got the AJAX call working however within the processing function I'm getting a server error that an `invalid argument was supplied for foreach`. Perhaps this is because the array I'm providing is a json array and it expects it to be a php array? If so, how can I convert the json array to php? I've googled with no luck.

Comment: how do i form and return the link?

Comment: when you create a file somewhere on server, you can form a link to it. Let say, your file is `/wp-content/uploads/zip-files/new.zip`, so link ot it will be `http://your-site/wp-content/uploads/zip-files/new.zip`. The simplest way - just echo it in your ajax php function and usr wp_die() as the next statement. Echoed string will be passed to your js.